# Background image not appearing that I set from Appdelegate

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

```
@objc let backgroundImg = UIImageView()

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    backgroundImg.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.window!.bounds.height * 1.688, height: self.window!.bounds.height)
    backgroundImg.image = UIImage(named: "mainbg.jpg")
    self.window!.addSubview(backgroundImg)
}
```

When I run the app on the Simulator the background picture doesn't show up.

Comment: Are you trying to add Splash Screen Image ??

Comment: Why you don't use the `view` of `window`'s `rootViewController`?

Comment: @Aditya Yes I'm trying to add an animating background.

Comment: Did you try using `LaunchScreen.xib`? You can set the image in this xib it should show up until your app launch.

Answer (score 0):

> the background picture doesn't show up.

You are saying:

```
self.window!.addSubview(backgroundImg)
```

Behind the scenes, the window is given a `rootViewController` whose main view is added as a subview to `self.window`. Therefore, the root view controller's main view is *covering* your `backgroundImg`.

You can easily confirm this by launching the app and then pausing in the View Debugger and examining the view hierarchy.